# Unable to add Hibernate dependency

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I am trying to create a new Maven project with Java and Spring Boot. To do this I used [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) with the following dependencies: Web, JPA, Mysql.
Along with those I want to use Hibernate(which I initially thought that would be brought by JPA dependency). My problem is that I don't have any Hibernate dependency in my pom.xml file and, when I try to add it, the configuration files(hibernate.cfg.xml) are not created.

How can I add Hibernate to this project?

Thank you

Comment: Some hibernate.cfg.xml is NOTHING at all to do with the JPA API. So if you are using JPA you aren't using that file ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question you need to understand a bit more of how Spring Boot Started are packaged.

In your initializer project's POM, you will see the following being added for JPA,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This is not a physical jar being included, this is a collection of other libraries, all added to another POM file. (You can scroll to the source a file)

In the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa POM you will see that Hibernate is already added as a dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.17.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Therefore you already have the hibernate dependencies added to your project.

Secondly, please have a look at 
https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-rest-api-tutorial-with-mysql-jpa-hibernate/

It is a tutorial that uses Spring-Boot's JPA and shows you how to configure it.

Comment: I initially thought that i don't have hibernate because after i created an entity and tried to add a record i got the error that the table was not found.How can i tell hibernate to create and run a create script based on my entity?

Comment: Did you set hibernate's hbm2ddl.auto to create?

Comment: Where should i put that property?I don't have a hibernate.cfg.xml file and it makes no difference if i put it in the application.properties.

Comment: With Spring boot you have an application.properties you can just add : spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create that should solve it. Is that what you added?

Comment: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto worked.It seems that what i've entered before was wrong.Thank you very much.